# iOS Close single-page automatic rotation iPad does not work?

Tags: ios, xcode, autorotate

Requirements: just can not automatically rotate a single page, go to horizontal screen outside always come in horizontal screen, vertical screen outside come in to keep the vertical screen.

Action: In the controller of this page and write shouldautorotate method returns NO, find work for all iphone have reached the demand, but the iPad is not working.

Note: Please see, it is a single, specific page without automatic rotation, which is to ensure the program settings page in several directions are checked, and the pull-down device along the shortcut menu to ensure open automatically rotated.

System: iOS9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar case. Note that I wasn't using navigation controller, it was a simple modal view being presented and this could affect the rotation code.

On the first view of my application I had:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

On the view that I wanted to lock on a certain orientation (landscape in my case) I didn't use the shouldAutorotate but used this one:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```